# Proof of Riemann integral as limit of Riemann integral sum

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

I want to Prove the following statement, I will be appreciate if some one help me to do that.

> Let $f:[a,b]\to R$  and $f$ is bounded, show that if $f \in R$  ( Riemann integrable) and $\int_a^b fdx=A$  $\iff$ (if and only if)
>   $$A= \lim_{d(p)\to 0} \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k^*)(x_k-x_{k-1})$$
>   where $d(p)$ is $\text{max}_{1\le k\le n}|x_k-x_{k-1}|$, ( the diameter of $p$, $p$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ and $\{x_k^*\}_{k=1}^n$ are sample points.

Note: I just know that we should show that for any partition and for any sample point corresponding to partition there exist such a limit and this limit is between upper Riemann sum and lower Riemann sum !

Comment: You need to tell us what your definition of $\int_a^b f\,dx$ is.  Saying that it is a "Riemann integral" is not enough: what is your definition of "Riemann integral"?

Comment: What have you tried? Indeed, if you'd like have any hints; you should show others your attempts. :-)

Comment: $f$ is bounded and  we want to show if  there is such a limit, the value of limit is equal to the  integral of $f$ in $[a,b]$ .And if $f$ is integrable the value of integral is equal to the value of limit.

Comment: Actually I make the question better but I just know that we should show that for any partition and for any sample point corresponding to partition there exist such a limit and this limit is between upper Riemann sum and lower  Riemann sum !

Comment: @mahsaghanbarpour: If you meant `Actually I make the question better. But what I just know is to show for any partition and for any sample point corresponding to partition, there exists such a limit and this limit is between upper Riemann sum and lower Riemann sum.` so add it below your question's body.

Comment: There are two definitions for the notion of Riemann Integral of a bounded function on a closed interval. I think you want to show the equivalence of these definitions. The proof is not obvious, but at the same time not too difficult either. Please see my answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1255344/72031