# properties of the integral (Rudin theorem 6.12c)

Tags: real-analysis

if $ f\in\mathscr{R(\alpha})$ on $[a,b]$ and if $a<c<b$, then $ f\in\mathscr{R(\alpha})$ $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$ and
$$\int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha = \int_{a}^{c}fd\alpha + \int_{c}^{b}fd\alpha$$

---

does the implication work backwards too? as in

if $ f\in\mathscr{R(\alpha})$ $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$ and $a<c<b$ then $ f\in\mathscr{R(\alpha})$ on $[a,b]$ and $$\int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha = \int_{a}^{c}fd\alpha + \int_{c}^{b}fd\alpha$$

i think it does and i've written a proof using upper/lower sums that seems trivial to me. but Rudin didn't write this as an "if and only if" statement so I'm suspicious that there might be a counterexample, perhaps with some weird discontinuity at $c$ for either $f$ or $\alpha$ that makes the backward implication not generally true.

Comment: I think you should be fine even with a discontinuity at $c$ as you only need to be continuous a.e. but this seems to be very subtle. Can you give the precise definitions of Riemann-integrable Rudin is using?

Comment: (Almost) quote from Wikipedia: "In general, the integral is not well-defined if $f$ and $\alpha$ share any points of discontinuity, but this sufficient condition is not necessary." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample from *Counterexamples in Analysis*: "functions $f$ and $\alpha$ such that $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$ on both $[a,b]$ and $[b,c]$, but not on $[a,c]$".
Let be
$$f(x) = 0,\ 0\le x<1,\qquad f(x) = 1,\ 1\le x\le 2.$$
$$\alpha(x) = 0,\ 0\le x\le 1,\qquad \alpha(x) = 1,\ 1< x\le 2.$$
Then,
$$\int_0^1 f\,d\alpha = 0,\qquad\int_1^2 f\,d\alpha = 1$$
and
$$\int_0^2 f\,d\alpha$$
does not exist.

Comment: so if $f$ and $\alpha$ do not share a common point of discontinuity, it works?

Comment: @somedude, I think that if all the integrals exists (is necessary but not sufficient that $f$ and $\alpha$ do not share a common point of discontinuity) then the equality is true. Check your proof with this hypothesis and post a new question if you want.

Comment: I just wanted put a comment, but my reputation is low...
Anyway, I think above counterexample is wrong, since $f$ is integrable on $[0,2]$.(See exercise 3 of rudin). Also, isn't the theorem works backward?

Comment: @quicksilver, see yourself the book: http://www.kryakin.org/am2/_Olmsted.pdf. $f$ is *Riemann* integrable, but not *Riemann-Stieltjes* integrable.

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla, I uploaded an answer. Can you check it out?

Comment: Based on the definitions of Riemann Stieltjes integration, your answer can be correct or can be incorrect. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The problem boils down to a proper definition of Riemann-Stieltjes definition. In this case Tom M. Apostol gives much better description (in his *Mathematical Analysis*) compared to Walter Rudin (in his *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*).

**Definition 1**: *Let $P = \{x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2},\ldots, x_{n}\}$ be a partition of interval $[a, b]$ and let $t_{k}$ be a point in the sub-interval $[x_{k - 1}, x_{k}]$. Let $f$ and $\alpha$ be functions defined and bounded on $[a, b]$. A sum of the form $$S(P, f, \alpha) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}f(t_{k})\{\alpha(x_{k}) - \alpha(x_{k - 1})\}$$ is called a Riemann-Stieltjes sum of $f$ with respect to $\alpha$ on $[a, b]$. We say that $f$ is Riemann integrable with respect to $\alpha$ on $[a, b]$, and we write "$f \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$" if there exists a number $I$ having the following property: For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a parition $P_{\epsilon}$ of $[a, b]$ such that for all partitions $P = \{x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2},\ldots, x_{n}\}$ of $[a, b]$ with $P \supseteq P_{\epsilon}$ and for every choice of $t_{k} \in [x_{k -1}, x_{k}]$ we have $$|S(P, f, \alpha) - I| < \epsilon$$*

When $\alpha$ is monotone on $[a, b]$ this definition coincides with the one based on upper and lower integrals given by Rudin.

Apostol mentions another definition of Riemann-Stieltjes integral in the exercises (Problem 7.3, page 174, *Mathematical Analysis*):

**Definition 2**: *Let $f$ and $\alpha$ be defined and bounded on $[a, b]$. We say that $f$ is Riemann integrable with respect to $\alpha$ on $[a, b]$, and we write "$f \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$" if there exists a number $I$ having the following property: For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a number $\delta > 0$ such that for all partitions $P = \{x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}\}$ of $[a, b]$ with norm $||P|| = \max_{k = 1}^{n}(x_{k} - x_{k - 1})< \delta$ and any choice of points $t_{k} \in [x_{k - 1}, x_{k}]$ we have $$|S(P, f, \alpha) - I| < \epsilon$$*

**Definition 1 is more general than definition 2** in the sense that if $f \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ based on definition 2 then $f \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ based on definition 1, but there are functions $f, \alpha$ such that $f \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ according to definition 1 and $f \notin R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ based on definition 2. An example is given in Problem 7.3(b), Page 174, Apostol' *Mathematical Analysis* which is integrable according to definition 1, but not according to definition 2 (this example is incidentally the same as the one given by Martin in his answer to the current question).

Moreover *if $\alpha(x) = x$ (so that we are just talking about plain Riemann integrability of $f$ on $[a, b]$) then both the definitions are equivalent* (proof is not trivial/obvious and is given in Problem 7.4, page 174, Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*).

Apostol uses definition 1 in his text and proves the following theorem:

**Theorem**: *Assume that $c \in (a, b)$. If two of the integrals in the equation below exist, then the third also exists and we have $$\int_{a}^{c}f\,d\alpha + \int_{c}^{b}f\,d\alpha = \int_{a}^{b}f\,d\alpha$$*

Moreover at the end of this theorem Apostol mentions the following note:

**Note**: *The preceding type of argument cannot be used to prove that the integral $\int_{a}^{c}f\,d\alpha$ exists whenever $\int_{a}^{b}f\,d\alpha$ exists. The conclusion is correct however.*

Apostol gives proof of existence of $\int_{a}^{c}f\,d\alpha$ based on existence of $\int_{a}^{b}f\,d\alpha$ in case when $\alpha$ is of bounded variation on $[a, b]$. However the proof for general bounded function $\alpha$ is based on different idea (Cauchy's criterion of integrability of interval functions, see page 22, *Functional Analysis* by F. Riesz and B. Nagy).

Based on definition 1, the claim by OP is correct. Also the counter-example by Martin in his answer is wrong. But if we use definition 2, then Martin's counter-example is correct and OP's claim is wrong. Thus it is a matter of definitions. In my opinion one should use the more general definition 1 compared to the slightly restrictive (but the one given originally by Riemann) definition 2.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches defining Riemann-Stieltjes integrabilities.

1. In Rudin's PMA, a function $f$ is r-s integrable w.r.t $\alpha$ when upper r-s integral and lower r-s integral coincides.

   In this case, backward implication also true. Furthermore, exercise 6-3 of rudin tells exactly when $f$ is r-s integrable w.r.t $\alpha$ under the condition $\alpha$ and $f$ have some same discontinuities.
   You can check Martin's counter-examlple is actually integrable in this definition.
2. Second approach is limiting 'length of partition' to zero. So in this definition, $f$ is integrable if

   For given $\epsilon>0$, there exist $\delta>0$ and $L$ such that
   $|R(f,P,Z) - L|< \epsilon $

   if  $||P||<\delta$

where $P=\{p_0,p_1, ... , p_n\}$ is a partition,$Z=\{z_0, ... z_{n-1}\}$ is a 'evaluation sequence' ,$R(f,P,Z)= \sum f(z_i)d\alpha _i$ is a riemann-stieltjes sum, $||P||= sup_{i<n}|p_i-p_{i-1}| $.
 In this case, backward implication is false and Martin's example is not integrable on $[0,2]$ since no matter 'small' $||P||$ is ,we can choose $\{z_i\}$ so that $R(f,P,Z)$ is either 0 or 1.

( Above discussion is due to 세아 from scieng.net)

Comment: What you say is correct. See more details in my answer. +1 for mentioning multiple definitions of integration.