# Why is the upper Riemann integral the infimum of all upper sums?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I was reading the theory of Riemann integration when I cam across the following ,

If $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, and $P = \{x_0,x_1,x_2.......x_n\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, let $$M_j = \sup_{x_{j-1}\leq x\leq x_j}f(x)$$ The upper sum of f over P is $$S(P) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} M_j(x_j-x_{j-1})$$ and the upper integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$, denoted by $$\int_{a}^{b^-} f(x)dx$$ is the infimum of all upper sums.

The theorem similarly goes on to state the result for lower sums.

My doubt is : I do not understand how is $$\int_{a}^{b^-} f(x)dx$$ the infimum of all upper sums. I understand that if we refine the partition P, then the upper sum would decrease, so it may be a lower limit for all the upper sums computed on the refinements of P (but still being the lower limit does not prove that it is the infimum) and what about those partitions for which P itself is the refinement of? 
How do I know that it will be a lower limit for those, let alone a infimum?

Comment: Do you have a definition of the upper integral other than "the infimum of all upper sums"?  From what you've written, it sounds like it's just the definition.

Comment: It's not a theorem; it's a definition.

Comment: @zhw  , But is it right to claim that we could just define that that particular limit which is what the integral basically is equals the infimum ?

Comment: @EricWofsey , I wanted to know that is the upper integral defined in this way a riemann integral too , that is if the partition goes to less than delta , then will my upper sum converge to it ?

Comment: Nice but slightly ambiguous question. +1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question does have some ambiguity. From the wording of your question and comments it appears that you want to know:

> Does the limit of upper sums (with respect to partitions getting finer and finer) equal the infimum of all upper sums?

---

First of all note that when we are dealing with limits of things dependent on a partition of an interval then there are two ways in which the limit operation can be defined:

1) **Limit via refinement of a partition**: Let $P = \{x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2},\ldots, x_{n} \}$ be a *partition* of $[a, b]$ where $$a =x_{0} < x_{1} < x_{2} < \cdots < x_{n} = b$$ A partition $P'$ of $[a, b]$ is said to be *a refinement* of $P$ (or *finer* than $P$) if $P \subseteq P'$.

> *Let $\mathcal{P}[a, b]$ denote the collection of all partitions of $[a, b]$ and let $F:\mathcal{P}[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. A number $L$ is said to be the limit of $F$ (via refinement) if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a partition $P_{\epsilon}\in \mathcal{P}[a, b]$ such that $|F(P) - L| < \epsilon$ for all $P \in \mathcal{P}[a, b]$ with $P_{\epsilon} \subseteq P$.*

2) **Limit as norm of parititon tends to $0$**: If $P = \{a = x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n} = b\}$ is a partition of $[a, b]$ then the *norm* $||P||$ of partition $P$ is defined as $||P|| = \max_{i = 1}^{n}(x_{i} - x_{i - 1})$.

> *Let $\mathcal{P}[a, b]$ denote the collection of all partitions of $[a, b]$ and let $F: \mathcal{P}[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. A number $L$ is said to be limit of $F$ as norm of partition tends to $0$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|F(P) - L| < \epsilon$ for all $P\in \mathcal{P}[a, b]$ with $||P|| < \delta$. This is written as $\lim_{||P|| \to 0}F(P) = L$.*

Note that for a given function $F:\mathcal{P}[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ the limiting behavior of $F$ can be different according to these two definitions given above. In fact if $F(P) \to L$ as $||P||\to 0$ then $F(P) \to L$ via refinement but the *converse may not hold in general*.

Let us establish that *if $F(P) \to L$ as $||P||\to 0$ then $F(P) \to L$ via refinement*. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary and let $\delta>0$ be such that $|F(P) -L|<\epsilon$ whenever $||P||<\delta$. Let us now choose any specific partition $P_{\epsilon} $ with $||P_{\epsilon} ||<\delta$. If $P_{\epsilon} \subseteq P$ then $$||P||\leq ||P_{\epsilon} ||<\delta\tag{A} $$ and hence by our assumption $|F(P) - L|<\epsilon $. Therefore it follows that $F(P) \to L$ via refinement also.

Notice that the argument here crucially hinges on inequality $(\text{A}) $. Starting with an $\epsilon>0$ we first found a $\delta>0$ via the given assumption $\lim_{||P||\to 0}F(P)=L$. The process of finding a suitable partition $P_{\epsilon} $ crucially depends on the implication $$P, Q\in\mathcal{P} [a, b], P\subseteq Q\implies ||Q||\leq||P||$$ which leads to inequality $(\text{A}) $ above. If the reverse implication $$P, Q \in \mathcal{P} [a, b], ||Q||\leq||P||\implies P\subseteq Q $$ *were true* then one could provide a similar argument as in last paragraph to prove that *if $F(P) \to L$ via refinement then $F(P) \to L$ as $||P||\to 0$*. We just need to set $\delta=||P_{\epsilon} ||$ and we are done. But this is not the case.

---

Now let $f$ be a function defined and bounded on $[a, b]$ and let $P = \{x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots x_{n}\}$ be a partition of $[a, b]$. Let $M_{k} = \sup\,\{f(x), x \in [x_{k - 1}, x_{k}]\}$ and let $\mathcal{P}[a, b]$ denote the collection of all partitions of $[a, b]$. We define the *upper sum* function $S:\mathcal{P}[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$S(P) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}M_{k}(x_{k} - x_{k - 1})$$ It is easy to prove that if $m = \inf\,\{f(x), x \in [a, b]\}$ then $S(P) \geq m(b - a)$ for all $P \in \mathcal{P}[a, b]$ and further if $P, P' \in \mathcal{P}[a, b]$ are such that $P \subseteq P'$ then $S(P') \leq S(P)$. It follows that $J = \inf\,\{S(P), P \in \mathcal{P}[a, b]\}$ exists.

Your question can now be worded more concretely into one of the following two forms:

> Does $S(P) \to J$ via refinement?

or

> Does $\lim_{||P|| \to 0}S(P) = J$?

The answer to the first question is obviously "yes" and you should be able to prove this using the definition of limit via refinement given above.

---

The answer to second question is also "yes" but it is difficult to prove. We first prove the result for a non-negative function $f$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Since $J = \inf\,\{S(P), P \in \mathcal{P}[a, b]\}$, there is a partition $P_{\epsilon} \in \mathcal{P}[a, b]$ such that $$J \leq S(P_{\epsilon}) < J + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\tag{1}$$ Let $P_{\epsilon} = \{x_{0}', x_{1}', x_{2}', \ldots, x_{N}'\}$ and let $M = \sup\,\{f(x), x \in [a, b]\} + 1$. Let $\delta = \epsilon / (2MN)$ and consider a partition $P = \{x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}\}$ with $||P|| < \delta$.

We can write $$S(P) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}M_{k}(x_{k} - x_{k - 1}) = S_{1} + S_{2}\tag{2}$$ where $S_{1}$ is the sum corresponding to the index $k$ for which $[x_{k - 1}, x_{k}]$ does not contain any point of $P_{\epsilon}$ and $S_{2}$ is the sum corresponding to other values of index $k$. Clearly for $S_{1}$ the interval $[x_{k - 1}, x_{k}]$ lies wholly in one of the intervals $[x_{j - 1}', x_{j}']$ made by $P_{\epsilon}$ and hence $S_{1} \leq S(P_{\epsilon})$ (note that $f$ is non-negative). For $S_{2}$ we can see that the number of such indexes $k$ is no more than $N$ and hence $S_{2} < MN\delta = \epsilon / 2$ (note that $f$ is non-negative here). It follows that $$J \leq S(P) = S_{1} + S_{2} < S(P_{\epsilon}) + \frac{\epsilon}{2} < J + \epsilon\tag{3}$$ for all $P \in \mathcal{P}[a, b]$ with $||P|| < \delta$. It follows that $S(P) \to J$ as $||P|| \to 0$.

Extension to a general function $f$ can be achieved by writing $f(x) = g(x) + m$ where $m = \inf\,\{f(x), x \in [a, b]\}$ and noting that $g$ is non-negative.

Another interesting example showing the difference between two limit definitions is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3130591/72031).

---

**Note**: The limit of a Riemann sum is based on the two definitions given above but there is a slight complication. A Riemann sum depends not only on a partition but also on choice of tags corresponding to a partition. Formally one can view a Riemann sum not as a function from $\mathcal{P} [a, b] $ to $\mathbb{R} $ but rather as a relation from $\mathcal{P} [a, b] $ to $\mathbb {R} $ such that it relates every partition of $[a, b] $ to one or more real numbers.

Comment: I guess I should start referring back to this as the definitive answer on the $\|P\| \to 0$ versus refinement question (+1).

Comment: @RRL: thanks for your encouraging words!

Comment: @Paramanand Singh, really elaborate answer that helped me a lot to grasp the idea of limits in terms of refinements. I was just wondering if the following statement should be the otherway round: instead of "This is because of the fact that refinement of a partition leads to a decrease in the norm, but decreasing the norm of a partition does not necessarily lead to a refinement." It should be: "This is because of the fact that refinement of a partition does not lead necessarily to a decrease in the norm, but decreasing the norm of a partition does lead to a refinement." Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Philipp: well you are wrong, but don't feel bad about it. Let me explain more. To refine a partition you add a point in existing partition. This process can never increase norm but may decrease it like from $\{1,3,4\}$ (norm $2$) to $\{1,2,3,4\}$ (norm $1$). On the other hand let's take a partition of norm $1/2$ say $\{0, 1/2,1\}$ and consider a partition $\{0,1/3,2/3,1\}$ of same interval $[0,1]$ with norm $1/3$. Clearly this is not a refinement of previous partition.

Comment: @Philipp: Also the language in my answer is imprecise (will fix it). What I wanted to say is this: Let $P, Q$ be two partitions of $[a, b] $. Then $P\subseteq Q\implies ||Q||\leq ||P||$ but $||Q||\leq ||P||$ does not necessarily imply $P\subseteq Q$.

Comment: @Philipp : I fixed my answer with more precise language. Thanks for noticing the problem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, first you state: "In fact if $F(P)\to L$ as $\Vert P\Vert \to 0$ then $F(P)\to L$ via refinement but the converse may not hold in general." For me this means on the one hand: "if $F(P)\to L$ as $\Vert P\Vert \to 0 \Rightarrow F(P)\to L$  via refinement" and on the other hand: "if $F(P)\to L$  via refinement $ \nRightarrow F(P)\to L$ as $\Vert P\Vert \to 0$". This is perfectly clear to me. However, I haven't fully understood the reason you presented for that. I will provide you with an example.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, for me the reason why you cannot convert the statement "In fact if $F(P)\to L$ as $\Vert P\Vert \to 0$ then $F(P)\to L$ via refinement" is simply the following counter example: Let $P=\{1,7,8\}$ a partitition and $P'=\{1,7,7.1,8\}$ is a refinement of $P$. One can see that both norms are still equal (namely $=6$). So refinement does not nessecarily decrease the norm and that is why the converse of "In fact if $F(P)\to L$ as $\Vert P\Vert \to 0$ then $F(P)\to L$ via refinement" is not generally true.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, With this in mind I don't understand your reasoning "This is because of the fact that refinement of a partition leads to a decrease in the norm, but a partition with smaller norm is not necessarily a refinement of a partition with a larger norm. Sorry for the lengthy comments but maybe you can help me to put my thoughts on this in order.

Comment: @Philipp : will add some explanation in my answer because adding too much in comments is not a good practice here.

Comment: @Philipp : check updated answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, thank you for your patience and your extensive explanation. Your update helped me a lot on that issue :)

Comment: In your second definition where you say "if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|F(P) - L| < \epsilon$ **for all** $P\in \mathcal{P}[a, b]$ with $||P|| < \delta$", I'm wondering why do you say that EVERY partition with norm less than $\delta$ should satisfy. Why isn't "**there exists** a partition $P$ with $||P||< \delta$" enough?

Comment: @William: the definition is designed to focus on the norm of the partition and the behavior should be seen for all partitions with small norm. Compare it with "all $x$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta $" in definition of limit.

Comment: Yes, that was actually my first thought. But I'm curious, would replacing *for all* with *there exists* work? I'm not able to see why it shouldn't.

Comment: @William: It won't work as we can then then find a set of partitions for which the integral would converge to some value and another set of partitions for which the integral would converge to another value.

Comment: Yes, that should be the logical conclusion but I've been at it for a while and that's what I can't produce, a counterexample that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, \exists P$ such that $||P||< \delta \Rightarrow |U(P,f)-L|< \epsilon$ would fail. (Taking $U(P,f)$ for example). The tricky part is that, I can always find partition for every $\epsilon$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh can u give a bit hint on how to show J is lower bound by having detail that S(P) converges to J via refinement?

Comment: @MEETPATEL: that's just using the definition. Since $J$ is the greatest lower bound of sums $S(P) $, given any $\epsilon >0$ there is a partition $P_{\epsilon} $ such that $J\leq S(P_{\epsilon}) <J+\epsilon $. If $P$ is finer than $P_{\epsilon} $ then we have $S(P) \leq S(P_{\epsilon}) $ and we are done using $J\leq S(P) <J+\epsilon $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh i think u make mistake;  plz read my question again; i want to prove J is lower bound;  and as a Hypothesis i have S(P) converges to J; via refinement

Comment: @MEETPATEL: note that convergence to a limit is unique and we have proved that the sums converge to the lower bound $J$. So putting it another way whatever limit the sums converge to is the lower bound. I don't think there is anything more to be proved here.

Comment: @MEETPATEL: If you wish you can give the argument from different direction. Let $S(P) \to L$ via refinement and let $J$ be greatest lower bound of sums like $S(P)$. Then for any $\epsilon >0$ we have a partition $P_\epsilon $ such that $L-\epsilon <S(P) <L+\epsilon $ for all $P$ with $P\supseteq P_\epsilon $. Now the lower bound $J\leq S(P) $ and hence $J<L+\epsilon $ and thus $J\leq L$. Derive a contradiction when $J<L$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I got your proof and tried but did not get contradiction,i know the fact that J is largest bound will use, and gap between J and L will also,.but not getting exact contradiction.plz give me hint how can i get?

Comment: @MEETPATEL: let $\epsilon =(L-J) /2>0$ and there is a partition $P'$ such that $J\leq S(P') <J+\epsilon $. And further we have a partition $P_\epsilon $ such that $L-\epsilon <S(P) <L+\epsilon$ for all $P\supseteq P_\epsilon $. The partition $P''=P' \cup P_\epsilon $ is finer than both $P'$ and $P_\epsilon $ and hence we have $J\leq S(P'') \leq S(P') <J+\epsilon$ and $L-\epsilon<S(P'') $. Next observe the contradiction because $J+\epsilon=L-\epsilon$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thank you !

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, thank you for a nice post. There are numerous posts on the site where authors use a sequence of partitions $P_n$. Would you put it this way then that a number $L$ is said to be the limit of $F$ (via refinement) if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $n>N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|F(P_n)-L)|<\epsilon$? Would you write this as $\lim_{n\to\infty}F(P_n)=L$?

Comment: The context in which this question arose is the following statement: $\lim_{\|P\|\to 0} L(f,P)=\sup_P L(f,P)$. Clearly the left-hand side is a limit as norm of partition tends to 0, but I am wondering if it can be rewritten in terms of limit via refinement, i.e. $\lim_{n\to \infty} L(f,P_n)=\sup_{P} L(f,P)$??

Comment: @schn: well you should ensure that the mesh/norm $||P_n||\to 0$. Any random sequence of partitions without that condition won't give us the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

You are having a fundamental misunderstanding on this topic for some reason. We have a bounded function. We define the upper integral. No question that it exists. We define the lower integral. Again, no question that it exists. We then define what it means for a bounded function to be Riemann integrable (RI): The uppper integral equals the lower integral. Plenty of questions about when this happens. The theory of the Riemann integral is all about when we are lucky enough to have $f$ RI, and about the value of the integral when it exists. For example, there is the theorem that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ then $f$ is RI on $[a,b].$ There is the FTC. A beautiful result of Lebesgue gives a necessary and sufficient condition: $f$ is RI iff $f$ is continuous a.e. All of these results go back to the definition.