# What does it mean for something to be strictly less than $\epsilon$ for an arbitrary $\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

Perhaps a trivial question, but something I never completely understood.  If we have shown that $a-b < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then does that imply that $a-b \le 0$?

I"m interested in it in the context of this question: [Proving that $ f: [a,b] \to \Bbb{R} $ is Riemann-integrable using an $ \epsilon $-$ \delta $ definition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255245/proving-that-f-a-b-to-bbbr-is-riemann-integrable-using-an-epsilon)

and in page 172 of these notes:  [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf)

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it does.

Suppose not. Then $a-b > 0$ and in particular we can take $\epsilon = a-b$. The statement then says that $a-b < a-b$, which is absurd.

Comment: To add to this answer, a common proof technique is to conclude that $a = 0$ from $|a| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Is there a constructive proof of this? I.e. one that doesn't use proof by contradiction or excluded middle?

Comment: You can formulate the same proof with contraposition. Is that good enough?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta not sure what you mean. Btw. my question was not directly addressed at you. Maybe I should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold You can take $\epsilon \to 0$ in a limit argument, but maybe this also implicitely uses what has to be proven