# Which equivalent definition used in below theorem.

Tags: measure-theory, riemann-integration

[image][image: first part][image: second part]

In proof of (change of variable in integration, which i uploaded ) which definition they used in equation (3) to show that function     on R.H.S in equation (3) is integrable?

My thoughts : if we already know the function we have is Reimann integrable, then to find its integral, we can restrict whatever we want (just it has to be subnet).and we can find its integral which is done in L.H.S Of  equation(3).

(1) Now what i mean by restriction: by restriction i mean we can find limit using only specific partitions(like equal sub interval).Or we can choose tags in some specific way(and partitions as well ).
I know if function we have is integrable then this all are just a subnet, so they will bring me to correct answer.

But in equation (3) they claimed function on R.H.S  is integrable ,by using specific tags(as you can see tags depend on Mean value theorem).
So My question is How this is sufficient to show that function is Reimann integrable?

Comment: The proof does not appear satisfactory to me. The integrability of $f(\phi(x)) \phi'(x) $ needs to be established first. And I doubt if there is a simple way to do. I will cross check some answers on mathse to see if it is available here already.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh if choice of tags was arbitrary(which is not here) then we can say this proof is perfect. Am i right?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote / close vote on this question.

Comment: And yes the proof would be correct if the choice of $\eta_i$ was arbitrary. The theorem however is correct.

Comment: You can also try to arrange the question into multiple paragraphs to improve readability. Maybe that's why someone downvoted.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh can i say proof will correct if choice of tags is like left part of each subintervals?(of course in this case it is not possible that those points are left part of subintervals).but this special choice lead us to existance?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh still learning to type mathematical  expression

Comment: What do they mean by $\mathbf R[a,b]$? As Paramand Singh has said, this proof requires already knowing that $\int_\alpha^\beta f(\phi(y))\phi'(y)\,dy$ exists. Saying that the $\eta_i$ or $\xi_i$ are any particular tags will not change that. Riemann integration requires that the summations for all possible choices of tags within their sub-intervals must converge. Instead, I believe they intended that their assumptions and previous results would be enough to show the integral converges (for example, if they have shown the products of integrable functions are integrable).

Comment: Can you let us know the textbook from where you have posted the image? I will check if related portions are available online and then figure out the intent of the author here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh added photo. Check question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof in your book has a subtle flaw as it does not assume the arbitrary tags $\eta_i$. One approach would be to assume the integrability of $f(\phi(y)) \phi'(y) $ and proceed as in the book.

Here is a way to deal with the situation in proper manner without assuming any extra hypotheses. Let's keep the notation as in your textbook and choose a random partition $Q=\{y_0,y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ of $[\alpha, \beta] $ and let $P=\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be the corresponding partition of $[a, b] $ so that $x_i=\phi(y_i) $. Note further that $$\Delta x_i=x_i-x_{i-1}=\phi(y_i)-\phi(y_{i-1})=\phi'(\theta_i)\Delta y_i\tag{1}$$ for some $\theta_i\in[y_{i-1},y_i]$. Since $\phi'$ is Riemann integrable over $[\alpha, \beta] $ therefore it is also bounded over same interval and let  $|\phi'(y) |< K$ for all $y\in[\alpha, \beta] $. We then have $$\Delta x_i< K\Delta y_i\tag{2}$$ Let $\eta_i\in [y_{i-1},y_i]$ be arbitrary tag points corresponding to partition $Q$ of $[\alpha, \beta] $ and let $\xi_i=\phi(\eta_i) $. Let $\epsilon >0$ be any pre-assigned arbitrary number. Then by Riemann integrability of $f$ on $[a, b] $ there exists a corresponding $\delta_1>0$ such that $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i-\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\right|<\frac{\epsilon} {2}\tag{3}$$ whenever $\mu(P) <\delta_1$.

Let $M$ be a positive upper bound for $|f|$ on $[a, b] $. Let $U(\phi', Q), L(\phi', Q) $ denote the upper and lower Darboux sums for $\phi'$ over partition $Q$ of $[\alpha, \beta] $ so that $$U(\phi', Q) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_i\Delta y_i, L(\phi', Q) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i\Delta y_i$$ where $M_i, m_i$ are supremum and infimum of $\phi'$ on $[y_{i-1},y_i]$. Since $\phi'$ is Riemann integrable on $[\alpha, \beta] $ there exists a $\delta_2>0$ such that $$U(\phi', Q) - L(\phi', Q) <\frac{\epsilon} {2M}\tag{4}$$ whenever $\mu(Q) <\delta_2$.

We now analyze the expression $$S=\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\phi(\eta_i)) \phi'(\eta_i) \Delta y_i-\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx\right|$$ Let $\delta=\min(\delta_1/K, \delta_2)$ and let $\mu(Q) <\delta$ so that by $(2)$ we have $\mu(P) <\delta_1$ and
\begin{align}
S&\leq \left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\phi(\eta_i)) \phi'(\eta_i) \Delta y_i-\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i) \Delta x_i\right|+\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i) \Delta x_i-\int_a^b f(x) \, dx\right|\notag\\
&<\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\phi(\eta_i)) ((\phi'(\eta_i) - \phi'(\theta_i)) \Delta y_i\right|+\frac{\epsilon} {2}\text{ (via (1) and (3))}\notag\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n|f(\phi(\eta_i))||\phi'(\eta_i)-\phi'(\theta_i)|\Delta y_i+\frac{\epsilon} {2}\notag\\
&\leq M \sum_{i=1}^n(M_i-m_i)\Delta y_i+\frac{\epsilon} {2}\notag\\
&= M(U(\phi', Q) - L(\phi', Q) +\frac{\epsilon} {2}\notag\\
&<M\cdot\frac{\epsilon} {2M}+\frac{\epsilon} {2}\text{ (via (4))}\notag\\
&=\epsilon\notag
\end{align}
It now follows that $f(\phi(y)) \phi'(y) $ is Riemann integrable over $[\alpha, \beta] $ with integral $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$.

The above also proves that if $\phi'$ is bounded away from zero in addition to the given hypotheses then $f(g(y)) $ is Riemann integrable on $[\alpha, \beta] $.

Comment: Got the entire proof ;thank you!